# Connect if disconnected and disconnect if connected with batch

Tags: windows, wireless-networking, command-line, batch, netsh

I'm trying to do a one-line batch command (for use with `autohotkey` with a keybaord shortcut) to:

- disconnect Wifi if it is connected: `netsh wlan disconnect`
- connect to SSID="MyWifi" if Wifi is currently disconnected: `netsh wlan connect ssid="MyWifi" name="MyWifi"`

This outputs some result if it is connected, and outputs nothing if it is disconnected:

```
netsh interface show interface |findstr /C:"Connected"
```

**How to use this in a `if else` condition?**

Example (pseudo code):

```
if ((netsh interface show interface |findstr /C:"Connected") == "")
then netsh wlan connect ssid="MyWifi" name="MyWifi"
else netsh wlan disconnect
```

Comment: You could compare the return code of `findstr` see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31810950/findstr-exit-codes-errorlevel)

Comment: Thanks @Aniket, how would you do the if else based on this return code, can you give an example of command line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a oneliner:

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion & netsh interface show interface |findstr /C:"Connected" & IF !ErrorLevel! EQU 0 (netsh wlan disconnect) else (netsh wlan connect ssid="mywifi" name="mywifi")
```

As a oneliner without setlocal:

```
(netsh interface show interface |findstr /C:"Conectado" && netsh wlan disconnect) || netsh wlan connect ssid="Galaxy21" name="Galaxy21"
```

Comment: Thanks! Is `setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion` here mandatory (why)?

Comment: yes, since you have to put it in one line...

Comment: If you don't need to put all commands in one line you could skip the setlocal part...

Comment: Basically Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion allows you to read the valure of variables in real time inside if or for loops...

Comment: Actually I send the answer for my windows version portuguese can you retest changing "Conectado" with "Connected"? maybe this is the error...

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

```
netsh interface show interface | findstr /C:"Connected"
if %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 0 (
    netsh wlan connect ssid="WifiName" name="WifiName"
) else (
    netsh wlan disconnect
)
```

Comment: Thanks for this solution!